# Angular-route bower download issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, git, bower

I have problem downloading angular-route through bower.json file. From what I see, today it (angular-route) got updated to version 1.5.4, yet downloading either 1.5.3 or 1.5.4 throws an error for me.

> PATH=.\node_modules.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web
>   Tools\External;%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\git "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\Bower.cmd" install --force-latest
>
> bower angular-route#~1.5.3  not-cached
>   https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-route.git#~1.5.3
>
> bower angular-route#~1.5.3     resolve
>   https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-route.git#~1.5.3
>
> bower angular-route#~1.5.3    checkout v1.5.3
>
> bower angular-route#~1.5.3     ECMDERR Failed to execute "git clone
>   https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-route.git -b v1.5.3
>   --progress . --depth 1", exit code of #-532462766

I have tried downloading it using:

> "angular-route": "*"
>
> "angular-route": "~1.5.3"
>
> "angular-route": "~1.5.4"

but i always get the same ECMDERR error. I have tried creating new project just to test if it works there but I get same results. I did not have problems downloading "angular" or any other packages.

Comment: Are you able to use `git` by itself? Doesn't look like a `bower` problem here.

Comment: What do you mean by "use git by itself"?

Comment: I mean, type `git` into the same console you're trying to run bower. Do you get an error? If so, that's your problem.

Comment: I'm running bower as a file in my project and to downlaod im just writting what and saving the file, so I don't know what kind of console am I supposed to use.

Comment: .. how are you running bower exactly? Are you typing `bower` into a terminal/command line somewhere? Open up a command line and type "git".

Comment: No. I have bower.json file in my project (mvc 6), whenever i want a package i write a line like this: "angular": "~1.5.3" and save the bower.json file, download happens automatically.

Comment: Oh... Visual Studio thing. Gotcha. Sorry, you lose me here. I'd perhaps start with trying to install/update git for Windows. https://git-scm.com/download/win

Comment: There's [no 1.5.4 release](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/tree/v1.5.4).

Comment: I think he/she is looking for `angular-route`, not `angular`.

Comment: So I have this command that is automatically generated by visual studio:
git clone https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-route.git -b v1.5.3 --progress . --depth 1

i tried running it in git command window and it failes too, but if i take away the . between --progress and --depth 1 it runs just fine and downloads the package. So now I have to either: 1) install the package from local destination or 2) make bower use edited git command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the bower.json file as another dependency I wrote:

```
"angular-route": "git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-route.git"
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug in the release process of AngularJS: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/14434

> More precisely, there was an issue with the release and not all modules have benn published.